# "roslaunch pi_tracker tracker.launch" - Can't find node

Tags: ros, roslaunch, pi-tracker, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ... logging to /home/geniusgeeko/.ros/log/eac7f5c6-4ff0-11e0-a4d0-904ce572720a/roslaunch-GG-Linux-Machine-2253.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
> Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
> Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is started roslaunch server http://GG-Linux-Machine:38241/
>
> ## SUMMARY
>
> PARAMETERS
>
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_foot
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_knee
> - /tracker_joint_controller/max_rotation_speed
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_knee
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_shoulder
> - /tracker_joint_controller/reverse_rotation
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_foot
> - /tracker_base_controller/scale_drive_speed
> - /tracker_base_controller/holonomic
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/neck
> - /tracker_joint_controller/holonomic
> - /tracker_command/default_joint_speed
> - /tracker_joint_controller/joint_controller_rate
> - /tracker_base_controller/scale_rotation_speed
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_shoulder
> - /tracker_joint_controller/fixed_frame
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_shoulder
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/torso
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_hip
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_hand
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/torso
> - /tracker_joint_controller/command_rate
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_elbow
> - /robotis_joint_controller/baud
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/neck
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_foot
> - /tracker_command/max_drive_speed
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/torso
> - /tracker_command/scale_drive_speed
> - /tracker_base_controller/max_drive_speed
> - /tracker_command/base_controller_rate
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_shoulder
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_hip
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_hand
> - /robotis_joint_controller/rate
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_foot
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_elbow
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_knee
> - /tracker_base_controller/use_real_robot
> - /tracker_command/reverse_rotation
> - /tracker_joint_controller/scale_rotation_speed
> - /tracker_base_controller/base_controller_rate
> - /tracker_base_controller/tracking_rate
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_elbow
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/head
> - /tracker_joint_controller/max_drive_speed
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/head
> - /tracker_command/fixed_frame
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_hand
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_hip
> - /tracker_command/tracking_rate
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_shoulder
> - /tracker_base_controller/reverse_rotation
> - /tracker_command/command_rate
> - /tracker_base_controller/default_joint_speed
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_shoulder
> - /tracker_base_controller/base_control_side
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_elbow
> - /tracker_joint_controller/default_joint_speed
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_knee
> - /tracker_command/use_real_robot
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_elbow
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_hip
> - /tracker_joint_controller/use_real_robot
> - /tracker_command/joint_controller_rate
> - /tracker_base_controller/command_rate
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_hip
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/head
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/neck
> - /tracker_base_controller/fixed_frame
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_knee
> - /tracker_joint_controller/base_controller_rate
> - /tracker_command/max_rotation_speed
> - /tracker_command/holonomic
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_hand
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/right_elbow
> - /robotis_joint_controller/port
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_hip
> - /tracker_command/scale_rotation_speed
> - /tracker_command/base_control_side
> - /tracker_joint_controller/base_control_side
> - /tracker_base_controller/joint_controller_rate
> - /tracker_command/skel_to_joint_map/left_hand
> - /tracker_base_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_knee
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/right_foot
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_foot
> - /tracker_base_controller/max_rotation_speed
> - /tracker_joint_controller/scale_drive_speed
> - /tracker_joint_controller/tracking_rate
> - /tracker_joint_controller/skel_to_joint_map/left_hand
>
> NODES
> /
> tracker_command (pi_tracker/tracker_command.py)
> tracker_base_controller (pi_tracker/tracker_base_controller.py)
> tracker_joint_controller (pi_tracker/tracker_joint_controller.py)
> robotis_joint_controller (pi_tracker/robotis_joint_controller.py)
>
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://GG-Linux-Machine:11311/
>
> core service [/rosout] found
> process[tracker_command-1]: started with pid [2274]
> process[tracker_base_controller-2]: started with pid [2275]
> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [pi_tracker/tracker_joint_controller.py]: Cannot locate node of type [tracker_joint_controller.py] in package [pi_tracker]

tracker_join_controller.py is clearly in the bin of the package also.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9447/%22roslaunch-pi_tracker-tracker.launch%22---can%27t-find-node/) by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure it's executable.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-16**:
To mark something solved please use the checkbox on an answer.

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-16**:
I hate when this happens, it just starting working out of the blue. /me sigh

**Comment by [GeniusGeeko](https://answers.ros.org/users/153/geniusgeeko/) on 2011-03-16**:
I did, it comes up with the same error.